# Original page not working after custom page deleted in Github Pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I added a custom page to a website I was hosting on Github Pages. But, it didn't work, so I removed it by blanking the custom domain name in Settings. However, when I tried the original page, it still redirects to the custom page, which does not work.

I originally thought caching was the problem, but it still persists after 10 minutes.

What's happening, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by clearing Google cache.